# Android Studio send data from device to other device via app

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, chat

I want to send listview from one device to other device like chat app.
Someone can help me and give idea or one way how to do this and which services i need to use to make it work?

Comment: use xmpp protocol is you want to send data like chat app

Comment: you have some guide or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

On Server Side Install Ejabberd Of Openfire ,I will Recommend Ejabberd

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu

Think Link Will Help You To Install Ejabberd

In Android Side

Install Asmack.jar and Follow This Tutorial

http://xmpp-tutorials.blogspot.in/